# Cannot read property 'Materials' of undefined. React useState with a nested object

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api, react-hooks

I'm trying to store the results of this API call into my state. When I attempt to call any of the objects the 'data' state in JSX, ex: data["Rank A: Real-Time Performance"].Materials, I get undefined errors . It works fine if the state variable is anything but a nested object. Can someone point me in the right direction please? I'm I doing something wrong, or is this bad practice? Thanks

This is an example of the API response

```
{
"Meta Data": {
    "Information": "US Sector Performance (realtime & historical)",
    "Last Refreshed": "04:20 PM ET 09/13/2019"
},
"Rank A: Real-Time Performance": {
    "Materials": "1.14%",
    "Financials": "0.84%",
    "Energy": "0.80%",
    "Industrials": "0.52%",
    "Communication Services": "-0.05%",
    "Health Care": "-0.07%",
    "Consumer Discretionary": "-0.19%",
    "Utilities": "-0.57%",
    "Information Technology": "-0.67%",
    "Consumer Staples": "-0.75%",
    "Real Estate": "-1.27%"
},
```

Here is the React code:

```js
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';


const SectorData = () => {
    let [data, setData] = useState({});

    async function fetchData() {
        try {
            const url = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=SECTOR&apikey=VZI9OTBHE0X9Y1JD";
            const response = await fetch(url);
            const json = await response.json();
            // This console log prints perfectly
            console.log("json = " + json["Rank A: Real-Time Performance"].Materials)
            setData(json)         
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    };
    useEffect(() => {  
        fetchData();
      }, [])

    return(
        <>
            {data["Rank A: Real-Time Performance"].Materials}
        </>
        
    )
}

export default SectorData
```

I found a fix by using next.js getInitialProps function.

But how would I go implementing an onload api call like this using just React?

Answer (score 2):

Initially `data` is an empty object. You're getting `undefined` because you're trying to access non-existent properties of that empty object. So add a condition that checks that you have no data (or an object with no keys). For example:

```
if (!Object.keys(data).length) return <div>No data</div>;

return (
  <>
    {data["Rank A: Real-Time Performance"].Materials}
  </>  
)
```